# Zlib dependency on Gitlab package for CentOS

Tags: ruby, centos, zlib, gitlab

I followed [this procedure](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/wiki/Import-existing-repositories-into-GitLab) to migrate gitolite repositories to gitlab on CentOS 6.4. The script halted with the following error:

```
[root@localhost gitlab-rails]# bundle exec rake gitlab:import:repos RAILS_ENV=production
rake aborted!
/lib64/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.3.3' not found (required by /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/libxml2.so.2) - /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so
```

What is the best way to provide the zlib 1.2.3.3 to the xml2 library pacakged with gitlab ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to install the library's by hit the following commands:

`yum install zlib-devel`

just in case if you install gitlab you may need the following also:

`yum -y install readline readline-devel ncurses-devel gdbm-devel glibc-devel tcl-devel openssl-devel curl-devel expat-devel db4-devel byacc gitolite sqlite-devel gcc-c++ libyaml libyaml-devel libffi libffi-devel libxml2 libxml2-devel libxslt libxslt-devel libicu libicu-devel system-config-firewall-tui python-devel`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already installed some of these, following the gitlab manual. zlib-devel was one of them. I have it at this location /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3

Comment: install also the others that i mention see if it solve your problem

Comment: I've just installed all these packages. It does not change the output of the script execution.